# Not able to make Put and Post requests on server when connection is mobile data xamarin forms

Tags: android, rest, xamarin.forms

When mobile is connecting to WIFI network application can easily communicate to server via api. Through wifi application can easily make get , put , post requests and getting desired result. When i changed my connection to mobile data , not able to make put , post request though get request worked fine. Thing is while connecting to mobile data , api hit cannot reach to server thats why i am not able to find if there is any server error. My current location is Lahore,Pakistan , i have checked it on different mobile network. What can be the reason of this ?

Comment: Where is your server?

Comment: Its an AWS server and region of server is Europe.

Comment: yes, also when you lost connection for second, we have same issue ?

Comment: the problem not from the 3G or 4G, i think the problem because mobile lost connection for seconds

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but @MikeDarwish it happened continuously. With same network get request is working fine , problem came when make put or  post request.

Comment: @HassanMunir, try to switch between 2 wifi networks, did you face same issue?

Comment: can you connect to the server using the device's browser while?

Comment: @Jason , sorry for late reply. We can connect to server through device's browser and can make get request but put/post request not working. Though when we make hit with no content at least hit made it to server.

Comment: @MikeDarwish , this is only happening when network is mobile data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening because of secure connection on mobile data , may b telecom carrier that i was using used some kind of firewall. Which didn't allow to make put request on insecure server. When i switched my server to https and made request then request successfully. So to make work you should have https server rather than http server.

Comment: ..could please send me, how to change secure connection on mobile data

Comment: @MikeDarwish , secure connection means the server with which you are communicating must by https secure server. Telecom carrier named "Zong" didnt allow to make post request on http server. So , by converting server to https my issue resolved.